# How to extract a number from a string using grep and regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I make a cat of a file and apply on it a `grep` with a regular expression like this

```
cat /tmp/tmp_file | grep "toto.titi\[[0-9]\+\].tata=55"
```

the command display the following output

```
toto.titi[12].tata=55
```

is it possible to modify my grep command in order to extract the number `12` as displayed output of the command?

Comment: You can add another `grep` or `sed` to cut this info out.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov I can do it by adding the following pipes to my command `| cut -f2 -d'[' | cut -f1 -d']'` but I want to know how to it with the same grep

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do it using just one single `grep`.

Comment: Yes it can be done in a single grep using `-P (PCRE)` switch. I provided an answer below.

Comment: @anubhava I m using a limited version of grep from busybox and it does not supported the -P option

Comment: Oh ok do you have egrep there?

Comment: @anubhava yes I have egrep

Comment: ok then it will have to be more than 1 egrep OR a single awk which one you prefer?

Comment: @anubhava I prefer `awk`

Comment: @anubhava you can show both alternatives in your answer

Comment: Ok I provided sed and awk options in my answer those are both 1 liners.

Comment: Also provided you a better pure BASH solution.

Comment: @anubhava thank you very much for your time and effort

Comment: You're welcome, hope one of those commands suite your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab this in pure BASH using its regex capabilities:

```
s='toto.titi[12].tata=55'
[[ "$s" =~ ^toto.titi\[([0-9]+)\]\.tata=[0-9]+$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
12
```

You can also use `sed`:

```
sed 's/toto.titi\[\([0-9]*\)\].tata=55/\1/' <<< "$s"
12
```

OR using awk:

```
awk -F '[\\[\\]]' '{print $2}' <<<"$s"
12
```

Answer (score 1):

use lookahead

```
echo toto.titi[12].tata=55|grep -oP '(?<=\[)\d+'
12
```

without perl regex,use sed to replace "["

```
echo toto.titi[12].tata=55|grep -o "\[[0-9]\+"|sed 's/\[//g'
12
```

Comment: I m using a limited version of grep from busybox and it does not supported the -P option

Comment: @MOHAMED what about sed?match [12 and use sed to replace [.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it to `sed` and use a back reference:

```
cat /tmp/tmp_file | grep "toto.titi\[[0-9]\+\].tata=55" | sed 's/.*\[(\d*)\].*/\1/'
```

Comment: You should now that `grep` can read files and `cat` is not needed.

Comment: @Jotne I do know that... I just took OP's partial solution and bolted on the extra part needed to do it